# JSON Form Population

Tags: jquery, json

I am following this tutorial on populating a dropdown menu using JSON http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

My JSON query is slightly different to the article (I attempted to create the same output from the article and failed), however from reading the comments it seems as though my output is the optimal choice.

MY JSON output is as follows:

```
{"beverages":["Coffee","Coke"],"snacks":["Chips","Cookies"]}
```

However the code below is not populating the drop down menu. I assume this is caused by a slightly different JSON output from the article? I have also included Papa's suggestion to remove the split from the code below as this is now redundant

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$("#first-choice").change(function() {

    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $.getJSON("../../getdata.php?getDropdown=yes&people_no=1", function(data) {

        var key = $dropdown.val();
        var vals = [];

        switch(key) {
            case 'beverages':
                vals = data.beverages;
                break;
            case 'snacks':
                vals = data.snacks;
                break;
            case 'base':
                vals = ['Please choose from above'];
        }

        var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
        $secondChoice.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
            $secondChoice("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });

    });
});
</script>

<select id="first-choice">
    <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
    <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
    <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
</select>

<br />

<select id="second-choice">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

Cheers

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi Felix, my question is that the code does not seem to populate the dropdown menu, so my assumption is that my code is wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use split as `data.beverages` is already an array.

```
vals = data.beverages;
```

---

Edit:

Found the issue. You're not appending the item to the dropdown correctly. Also use the above to select the values.

```
$secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
```

Comment: Hi Papa, thanks for this, I actually tried removing this (but forgot to include it in the code), however it still does not populate the drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have literally spent more than 8 hours trying to solve this, I really wish there was a feature to buy somebody a beer on this site!!!